# How to upload a file to google disk api

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api

I have web site with many images, I want to upload all the images to google disk, can you help me, how I can download file from url to google disk, without downloading to my host and after upload to google disk.

for example [yandex disk](https://tech.yandex.com/disk/api/reference/upload-ext-docpage/) have this api but in google I can't find enough details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- you can use [PyDrive](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyDrive)
this is how it works:

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
my_file = #the file you want to be uploaded or sth else
my_file.Upload()
```

2- or you can also run your app without help of wrappers which is well documented by google here for [submit your app](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/python) and then here for [upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-uploads)